# Send additional header to FastCGI backend with nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers, fastcgi

I use nginx with several fastcgi backends (php-cgi, mod-mono-fastcgi4). Now I need to sent an additional http header to the fastcgi backend, basically the same as proxy_set_header does when using nginx as reverse proxy. But to my findings, there is no such thing as fastcgi_set_header in nginx.

Somebody got any ideas how to do this anyways? I dont want to use additional nginx modules as the solution muste be easily deployable on a wide range of customer systems.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I took a quick look at the manual and I think the closest you will find is passing fastcgi parameters:

> The request headers are transferred to the FastCGI-server in the form of parameters. In the applications and the scripts run from the FastCGI-server, these parameters are usually accessible in the form of environment variables. For example, the header "User-agent" is transferred as parameter HTTP_USER_AGENT. Besides the headers of the HTTP request, it is possible to transfer arbitrary parameters with the aid of directive fastcgi_param.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule#Parameters.2C_transferred_to_FastCGI-server.

> fastcgi_param
>
> syntax: fastcgi_param parameter value

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_param

Comment: I've found that, too. However, fastcgi_param are used to set variable that are send to the FastCGI server - not HTTP Headers. The problem is you can't access the fastcgi variables from within the application (which is a php script or a asp.net webapp).

Comment: I got it working now using 'fastcgi_param HTTP_X_MYVAR "myvalue";'. If the variable name starts with HTTP_ it seems it gets copied over to the headers. However, this is undocumented and implementation specific and might change with future releases

Comment: Good find, Dyna. I'll make note of that.

Comment: Hi both, check out $_SERVER in PHP to see fastcgi_params. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098927/nginx-variables-similar-to-setenv-in-apache

Comment: @Dynalon is incorrect. FastCGI parameters are accessible in the `$_SERVER` superglobal in PHP.

Comment: Given that my posting is from 2012, the situation today in PHP might be different then back then.

Answer (score 11):

The URLs to the nginx wiki articles above are broken.

nginx exposes request header values via variables prefixed with **$http_**, so a request header of **HTTP_USER_AGENT** is available via **$http_user_agent**.

Likewise a request header named **CHICKEN_SOUP** would be available via **$http_chicken_soup**.

The example below shows how to pass the the **Authorization** HTTP request header to PHP scripts running under php-fpm (PHP FastCGI process manager).

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/path/to/socket;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  HTTP_AUTHORIZATION $http_authorization;
    ... other settings
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer of this topic. This configuration works well. Other answers does not work. but there is some hint. any underlines are usually removed. then for example variable CHICKEN_SOUP is presented both as CHICKENSOUP and HTTP_CHICKENSOUP in environment if you add config 'fastcgi_param CHICKENSOUP $http_chickensoup . Unfortunately $http_chicken_soup is inaccessible, I've spend some time for debug this one.

Comment: The example makes no sense whatsoever. NGINX will automatically pass *all* client request headers over to PHP-FPM.

Answer (score 0):

I take as good Zoot's answer, and based on it, I'd like go further for whoever it can help. In order to cover both scenarios, "reverse proxy with upstream" and "standalone", so I'll post what I've done to accomplish the task to forward the proper headers to the "last" server, so the app can have the necessary info (via `SSL_*` headers) to assign proper user identification instead of just allow pass regardless the identity. The examples cover php and fastcgi, but I'm sure they can be easily adapted to other stacks, if necessary:

First, in a "standalone" server (i.e. no reverse proxy in between), which performs the verification:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

...

    ssl_certificate /etc/XXX.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/XXX.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/XXX/CA.pem;
    ssl_verify_client optional; # Or whatever

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php;
        # The provided fastcgi script by nginx
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # A custom snippet to manage headers
        include snippets/sslclient-fastcgi.conf;

    }
}
```

The custom `sslclient-fastcgi.conf`:

```
# Custom snippet to be used in a standalone server that performs verification
# by using a x509 client certificate. The nginx variables are transformed into
# SSL_* headers (trying to mimic Apache documentation with StdEnvVars and ExportCertData)
# and passes the result to an upstream using cgi to process headers.

fastcgi_param SSL_CIPHER $ssl_cipher;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_CERT $ssl_client_raw_cert;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_I_DN $ssl_client_i_dn;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_S_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_V_END $ssl_client_v_end;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_V_REMAIN $ssl_client_v_remain;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_V_START $ssl_client_v_start;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY $ssl_client_verify; # “SUCCESS”, “FAILED:reason”, and “NONE”
fastcgi_param SSL_PROTOCOL $ssl_protocol;
fastcgi_param SSL_SERVER_S_DN $ssl_server_name;
```

This way, the app just has to read the proper `SSL_*` headers and manage according to the contents.

Next, the scenario with a reverse proxy (which performs the verification) and forwarding the results to an upstream http server. First, the relevant parts of the reverse proxy:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

...

    ssl_certificate /etc/XXX.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/XXX.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/XXX/CA.pem;
    ssl_verify_client optional; # Or whatever

    ## PROXY backend
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://upstream:8080;

        # The included file in nginx installation
        include proxy_params;

        # Custom snippet to manage the proxy headers
        include snippets/proxy_ssl_client-upstream.conf;
    }

}
```

The `proxy_ssl_client-upstream.conf` file:

```
# Snippet to be included in a reverse proxy server to catch the custom SSL_* headers
# (which will be seen as HTTP_SSL_* in the upstream) during the SSL verification process
# performed in the same proxy server, These headers should be transformed back
# to SSL_ for the web app, by using the corresponding
# $http_* variables generated by nginx. The web app should take care of
# SSL_* headers only.

# The set of headers, trying to mimic as much as possible the same headers
# that Apache generates via StdEnvVars and ExportCertData options in a SSLOptions directive

proxy_set_header SSL-CIPHER $ssl_cipher;
proxy_set_header SSL-CLIENT-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
proxy_set_header SSL-CLIENT-I-DN $ssl_client_i_dn;
proxy_set_header SSL-CLIENT-S-DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
proxy_set_header SSL-CLIENT-V-END $ssl_client_v_end;
proxy_set_header SSL-CLIENT-V-REMAIN $ssl_client_v_remain;
proxy_set_header SSL-CLIENT-V-START $ssl_client_v_start;
proxy_set_header SSL-CLIENT-VERIFY $ssl_client_verify; # “SUCCESS”, “FAILED:reason”, and “NONE”
proxy_set_header SSL-PROTOCOL $ssl_protocol;
proxy_set_header SSL-SERVER-S-DN $ssl_server_name;
```

And finally, the relevant parts of the upstream server:

```
server {                                
        listen 8080;

...                                                     

    # PROD
    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php;
        # The standard snippet provided by nginx
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # A custom snippet to manage the headers forwarded by the reverse proxy
        include snippets/proxy_ssl_client-fastcgi.conf;
    }
```

The included `proxy_ssl_client-fastcgi.conf`:

```
# Snippet to be included in an upstream server to catch the custom HTTP_SSL_* headers
# generated by another custom snippet during the SSL verification process
# performed by a reverse proxy server. This snippet transforms these generated
# HTTP_SSL_* headers as SSL_* to the web app via fastcgi, by using the corresponding
# $http_* variables generated by nginx. The web app should take care of
# SSL_* headers only.

fastcgi_param SSL_CIPHER $http_ssl_cipher;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_CERT $http_ssl_client_cert;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_I_DN $http_ssl_client_i_dn;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_S_DN $http_ssl_client_s_dn;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_V_END $http_ssl_client_v_end;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_V_REMAIN $http_ssl_client_v_remain;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_V_START $http_ssl_client_v_start;
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY $http_ssl_client_verify; # “SUCCESS”, “FAILED:reason”, and “NONE”
fastcgi_param SSL_PROTOCOL $http_ssl_protocol;
fastcgi_param SSL_SERVER_S_DN $http_ssl_server_s_dn;
```

I hope this can help to get rid of any issues about how to manage the ssl client certificates in nginx.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the third party module [ngx_headers_more](https://github.com/agentzh/headers-more-nginx-module). After building nginx with this module included, you can do the following in your configuration:

```
location / {
    more_set_input_headers 'Foo: bar baz';
    ...
}
```

Comment: it is completly unnecessary. resolve wroten by @zoot is enough with standard modules. then you don't need any recompilation.

Answer (score -1):

Nginx now has:

```
fastcgi_pass_header 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate';
```

Which can be used in your location rules if you are adding headers which aren't already specified in your request. By default fastcgi uses:

```
fastcgi_pass_request_headers on;
```

Which will pass all incoming Headers from the request to fastcgi.

Comment: @Dyna No, it should not. @Derek Dowling : Your first solution is wrong, `fastcgi_pass_header` does the opposite of what you explain : it permits passing header(s) from the fastcgi server reply back to the client, not from the initial request to the fastcgi server. The intention of this directive is to keep in the reply special headers that can be interpreted by reverse proxies (like `X-Accel-Buffering`, `X-Accel-Limit-Rate` etc) in some specific cases.

Comment: It isn't corrent according to doc :
Permits passing otherwise disabled header fields from a FastCGI server to a client.