# How to set custom $_SERVER variables from client in PHP

Tags: php

According to this post: [Which $_SERVER variables are safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474783/which-server-variables-are-safe) and another I've seen, a client seems to be able to set custom $_SERVER variables. For example: $_SERVER['HTTP_EXAMPLE']

How would a client actually set a value to $_SERVER['HTTP_EXAMPLE']?

Comment: No better place to start than reading the manual http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: That's an awesome answer Fred, Thanks for your input about reading the manual.

Answer (score 16):

If you have access to the Apache config file, you can do it using [mod_env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv)

```
SetEnv HTTP_EXAMPLE http_example
```

Then you can access that variable

```
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_EXAMPLE"]; //outputs http_example
```

Comment: I mean from the client side, not the server side. A client who wouldn't have access to apache configuration.

Comment: I like this solution. Wrangling docker environments made easier.

Comment: For nginx (**php-fpm**) you may want to declare this variable through a `fastcgi_param`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331663/6225838

Answer (score 7):

You can just set the variable in your script if you want

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = 'test';
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];  // test
```

What that other article is really referring to spoofed variables such as the `REMOTE_ADDR` which is reported by the client.

For more info on that check out this post on faking the REMOTE_ADDR. [How to fake $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092563/how-to-fake-serverremote-addr-variable)

Comment: I mean from the client side, not the server side. A client who wouldn't have access to raw PHP code. The other article also lists "any other 'HTTP_' value" under client side set.

Comment: Updated with a link to a related post. It's kind of an open ended question as there are many potential ways to mess about with things

Comment: I guess this `$_SERVER["variable"]` can be used to store a global variable