# Cannot access ubuntu's environment variables from PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I'm making a codeigniter website and i need to switch configs between production and development. By default Codeigniter searches for the var `CI_ENV` in PHP's `$_SERVER` superglobal. However when i'm trying to set my own with

`$ CI_ENV=production
$ export CI_ENV`

in my production server.

When i'm trying to access it from `$_ENV`, `$_SERVER` or `getenv()` it's not there.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, Codeigniter looks for Apache ENV variables, not system variables.

In your vhosts.conf or .htaccess file add the following:

`SetEnv CI_ENV production`

If you add this to your vhosts.conf file you will need to restart Apache.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, nginx wasn't mentioned in your post so I assumed it was Apache. Nginx doesn't really handle ENV variables by default, but there are some workarounds: http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env  and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8331663/5505288 might help.