# Set custom environment variable to psgi hash plack

Tags: perl, hash, plack, psgi

When I do a request to dumper $env I get all data of enviromment hash psgi, in this example

```
sub { 
  my $env = shift;  
  return [ 200, [], [ $env->{REMOTE_ADDR} ] ];  
}
```

or more directly

```
sub { 
  return [ 200, [], [ shift->{REMOTE_ADDR} ] ];   
}
```

Output:

**Returns the IP address of the client**

How I can set my own **custom environment variable to psgi hash plack** ?

why I want to do that, my case is relation to:
[Nginx variables similar to SetEnv in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098927/nginx-variables-similar-to-setenv-in-apache)

If not possible to do that, **can I create subclass and add that functionality to psgi web server ?**

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to set variables within the application server, this looks like the perfect case for some plack middleware. For this case, I found [Plack::Middleware::ReviseEnv](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Middleware::ReviseEnv), which is usable within your app.psgi:

```
# app.psgi
use Plack::Builder;

my $app = sub {
    return [ 200, [], [ shift->{var} ] ];
};

builder {
    enable "ReviseEnv", revisors => { 'var'  => 'custom',
                                      'var2' => 'other' };
    $app;
};
```

The documentation also lists additional options for setting values beyond simple text, such as including other `$env` data or `%ENV` environment variables.