# Where (i.e. which file) to set/assign systemwide environment variable which e.g., nginx can read like NODE_ENV on FreeBSD?

Tags: environment, freebsd, rc

On [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/), I need `NODE_ENV=production` and other systemwide environment variables to be set on startup, before nginx fires up.

Which is the right place i.e. file I do that?

Comment: How do you run nginx? Manually, or as a service (`/etc/rc.conf`)?

Comment: Thanks for asking, sorry I wasn't specific. I run it as a service.

Comment: Then, I think, the correct solution would be to set env vars by Nginx. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331663/637669

Comment: That's what I am doing at the moment. But I want need to have some of the variables at other places too. Therefore I'd like them to be available globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to add your environment variables to `/etc/login.conf` in the `setenv` capability, for example:

```
default:\
    :passwd_format=sha512:\
    :copyright=/etc/COPYRIGHT:\
    :welcome=/etc/motd:\
    :setenv=MAIL=/var/mail/$,BLOCKSIZE=K,NODE_ENV=production:\
    ...
```

From the [login.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?login.conf(5)) man:

> ```
> setenv          list           A comma-separated list of
>                                environment variables and
>                                values to which they are to
>                                be set.
> ```

If you modity the `/etc/login.conf` file, don't forget to run:

```
cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you'd like to set some environment variables for an [rc(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?rc) service then you might also take a look at the `${name}_env` and `${name}_env_file` variables described in [rc.subr(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?rc.subr). They allow you to set environment variables for services on FreeBSD in [rc.conf(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?rc.conf), e.g.:

```sh
nginx_enable="YES"
nginx_env="NODE_ENV=production"
```